# How do I maximize XP gain?

Tags: pokemon-go

Obviously, I could level up faster as a trainer by playing all day long; but that is hardly feasible. There are various activities that give XP, some of them are controllable (like winning in gym battles) and others are somewhat random (getting a new pokemon).

Other than normal gameplay like capturing all the Pokemon I see, what actions lead to more efficient xp gain? Esp. when it comes to using limited resources - e.g. I will run low on potions if I battle often, should I focus on friendly challenges or gym takeovers to efficiently use my potions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have an exhaustive list, but I do have one tip that would be very efficient.

Lucky Eggs are items that double the XP you earn for 30 minutes. The ideal time to use these is when you have prepped yourself to maximize your XP gain. Some great conditions to use an egg would be when:

- You'll be staying at a Pokestop and have Lures and Incense to use
- You have a lot of Pokemon ready to evolve. Evolving Pokemon provides quite a bit of XP.
- Getting Nice/Great/Excellent throws. Each of these require you to throw the Pokeball within the targeting circle. Nice throws happen when the circle is large, while excellent throws happen when the circle is pretty small. They add a bonus of 10, 50, and 100 XP on a successful capture respectfully.

So far, I've gotten Lucky Eggs from leveling up. You can also purchase them from the shop. If you hold off on evolving and get comfortable at a Pokestop, you could gain quite a bit of XP in a short amount of time with the use of a Lucky Egg.

Comment: +1 i've used this a couple times now, and it's very effective. just go nuts in those 30 short minutes

Comment: You can get a tad bit more bonus XP if you also throw a "Curve Ball." Swirl the ball before throwing it, and it'll curve (clockwise, throw to the left of the screen).

Comment: I would include egg hatching in this list. You get XP for the hatch and if it is a new Pokemon.

Comment: Evolving gave me a ***ton*** of XP (1000 seemed like a lot for a level 5) so yeah, that should be the #1 point.

Answer (score 9):

The single fastest way to get XP is to save up tons of level 1 evolution of your local pokemon that evolve with just 12 candies.

you get 500 exp for every evolution, so if you save up 12 pidgeys and have 144 candies, and then pop a lucky egg you will make 12,000 experience in just a few minutes.

So save your evolution's to use with lucky eggs. 
[image]

Comment: Note that for these 12 candy pokemon, the best way to manage your candy is to catch the following sequence of numbers of them, evolving one in each set and transferring the rest: 4,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,... Your supply of candy then proceeds like 0,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,8,...

Comment: @Ian you drunk bro

Comment: Actually, sorry, the calculation I did ignored the fact that you need to hold onto the ones you are going to evolve in order to use a lucky egg. You should instead catch a bunch of Pidgeys, transfer 64% of them, and evolve the remaining 36% when you use your lucky egg. If you transfer the Pidgeottos as you go, you'll be able to evolve them all. This gives you the most evolution XP per total number of Pidgeys you catch.

Comment: Example: catch 100 Pidgeys, transfer 64 Pidgeys, you now have 364 candy. Evolving the remaining 36 Pidgeys takes 432 candy. But each Pidgey you evolve generates 2 candy (1 for evolving, 1 for transferring). So by the end of the whole process you have generated 436 candy, which is enough to do 36 evolutions.

Answer (score -1):

Use a lucky egg and win a raid battle a gym of enemy color when the raid is about to expire, then clear out the gym when the raid boss goes away. then evolve stuff.

Alternatively, purchase 100 dollars of Pokemon coins, spend a lot of money on everything and party hard.

Answer (score -3):

get as many phones as possible use them as feeder to your 'main'.  So when you reach a pokestop use all the potions you gather to revive pokemon.  Beat them down with your main.  Fight gyms with your main.  That way you'll gain xp for your main without taking damage.

Comment: I didn't understand, do you mean I need multiple accounts on different phones to do this? How would I even use an alt a/c as feeder, since there is no pokemon or item transfer between accounts afaik?

Comment: No use battle the pokemon on the feeder account without taking any damage. that will ensure you have maximal potion usage for gym encounters.  Use all the potions on your alt to restore health for feeder battles.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer for Pokemon Go. If it is, it's not clear how you would actually do what it suggests.

Comment: you dont battle any other pokemon but gyms, in the first place..

Comment: @Timelord64 you can't battle other Trainers????

Comment: Why are you answering this question if you don't know how Pokemon GO works?

Comment: no..  you cant.  only gyms.

Comment: Not only does this not work (at all, for many reasons), but it is against the ToS of the game. One account per person, or you could be banned.

Comment: @GreySage look at this Ikeman!  Only winning matters when it comes to pokemon training